# Insert character in a string in dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

input:

```
{
  "string": "putbackthespaces",
  "indexes": [
    3,
    8,
    12
  ]
}
```

output:

```
{
  "string": "put back the spaces"
}
```

I want to insert a character (in this particular example, spaces will be inserted) at a particular index specified by the elements in payload.indexes. The catch here is that the transformation can only be done using mule flows together with dataweave.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a recursive function to apply the inserting for each char:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun insertChar(s, n, c)=s[0 to n-1] ++ c ++ s[n to -1]
fun insertAllChars(s, a, c)=
    if (sizeOf(a)>0) 
        insertAllChars(
            insertChar(s, a[0], c), 
            slice(a,1, sizeOf(a)), 
            c
        ) 
    else s
---
{
    string: insertAllChars(payload.string, payload.indexes , " ")
}
```